# Can you use multiple displays with out an extra video card?

Tags: vga, external-display

Is it at all possible to use multiple displays with only a built in VGA output and no DVI output available?

Comment: You could also try something like http://www.maxivista.com/  It runs through the LAN.  Pretty neat tool, actually.

Comment: good question...+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding an extra video card, it might or it might not depending on your system's configuration. A more elegant and better solution would be using an extra video card that has multiple outputs.

***UPDATE:***

Without adding an extra card, splitting the signal might be possible, but this would not add an "extra" display, merely a duplicate.

What a splitter would look like:

[image: VGA Splitter]

***UPDATE 2:***

DVI in fact, might not even work AT ALL since it has restrictions.