# Dual monitors with only one VGA port

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I am trying to use multiple monitors. Both monitors have VGA connectors while my computer only has one VGA and one HDMI connection.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use multiple displays with out an extra video card?](http://superuser.com/questions/151849/can-you-use-multiple-displays-with-out-an-extra-video-card)

Comment: Can you clarify "multiple screens". Do you want to clone or extend your desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a HDMI-to-VGA converter for your HDMI output. You can then have both monitors connected and work as cloned or extended desktops.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway around this?

Yes. You can either:

1. Buy an (expensive) HDMI to VGA convertor. This is an active device, not merely a cable with different plugs on both ends.
2. Buy a second graphics card with a VGA output and use both VGA outputs. This should work on any recent OS.  (Read: not with Xp or earlier).
3. Buy a monitor which has modern inputs (VGA is 26+ years old and has long since been replaced by DVI. And DVI itself has already been replaced by HDMI and DP).
4. Or, if you want to show the same image on both screens: You can use a VGA splitter. Basically an `Y` cable.  But this will output the same signal to both monitors. Same resolution, same image.

Option 1 sounds good, but given the price of these devices vs a cheap new monitor the latter option might actually be better.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a VGA splitter to do that. You can pick that up at any best buy or radio shack

Comment: A splitter will do exactly that. It will send the one VGA signal to both screens - i.e. both screens will display the same image. This won't work for if the user wants to extend desktops, for example.

Comment: Ah yes there is that. Any way to configure it in windows to extend it?

Comment: Not using a "splitter". A splitter (in almost all circumstances) is a "Y" cable where two VGA cables have been pinned together so you will never be able to do anything like extend a desktop )because the video output is different for each screen) - logical? The OPs laptop has BOTH a VGA and HDMI output - this will give the separate video signals that will allow the extended desktop functionality - BUT, as the OP states, the monitors are VGA only so you need to CONVERT the HDMI (digital) to VGA (analog) thus a converter is required.